# Is there a way to share a NetworkStream or TCPClient object between services in .net

Tags: .net, windows, sockets

I have a windows service that is listening on a specific port and for each connection, it creates a new thread that is reading the incoming data. In another windows service, I want to send data to the same client. However, the client cannot be identified from this service since it has a dynamic IP.

Is there a way in .NET or any other framework to use directly the existing NetworkStream in another process/service. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You should research IPC (inter-process communication). But from my understanding you cannot share memory/objects between processes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that you can do this and even if there was it would not be recommended.

There are other methods for inter-process communication such as named pipes, remoting and WCF to name a few.

Comment: I was thinking the same. Thanks.